# How to do Caching and Dependency Injection outside of Controller in .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I've used DI purely for tests within a controller and I'm oddly having a real hard time using it outside of a controller. I had a static caching class called caching engine, but apparently DI and static classes don't mix well, so I decided to make it non-static instead. However, I can't get this to work well and I'm not sure what the best approach is. I have a controller that I need to pass products and send them to the view. However, for speed improvements, I'd like to use memory caching, but I'm really confused on the best design here. I'd like to know the best way to do this.

1) How does instantiating a new class work with DI if you don't pass the dependencies?

2) Should I inject my memorycache and product repository into the controller and then pass them into the cachingengine constructor? That seems like a lot of unnecessary parameter passing, so I didn't like this.

3) Should I just instantiate a MemoryCache class in the caching engine and not worry about DI?

4) Should I just switch the CachingEngine back to a static class?

Thank you for your help and advice. It is much appreciated.

Here's the Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Add Dependencies
        services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();

        //Extention method that sets up the shared objects used in MVC apps
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        ....
    }
}
```

Here's the Controller

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    private CachingEngine engine;

    public MainController()
    {
        //This isn't valid, missing parameters
        engine = new CachingEngine();
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var products = CachingEngine.GetProducts();
        ....
    }
}
```

And here's the caching class:

```
public class CachingEngine
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache memoryCache;
    private IProductRepository prodRepo;

    public CachingEngine(IMemoryCache memory, IProductRepository rep)
    {
        memoryCache = memoryCache;
        prodRepo = rep;
    }

    public List<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        var cacheKey = "Products";
        List<Product> prods;
        if (memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out prods))
        {
            return prods;
        }
        else
        {
            memoryCache.Set(cacheKey, prodRepo.Products);
            return prods;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, to clarify, a static class cannot be instantiated so how could you inject instantiations into its constructor using a dependency injection framework. It is not that static classes do not work well with DI, they do not work at all and make no sense in the context of dependency injection.

Your Controller needs a CachingEngine, so you need to inject it, a simple rule of setting up DI in your software: do not use the `new` operator.

Anytime you use the `new` operator you are tightly coupling your code to a particular type and you have the exact problem that Dependency Inject is trying to solve.

```
public class Startup
{

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {

    //Add Dependencies
    services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();

    //configure DI for IMemoryCache and CachingEngine
    services.AddTransient<IMemoryCache, MyMemoryCacheClass>();
    services.AddTransient<MyICachingEngineInterface, CachingEngine>();

    //Extention method that sets up the shared objects used in MVC apps
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    ....
   }
}

public class MainController : Controller
{

    private readonly MyICachingEngineInterface _cachingEngine;

    public MainController(MyICachingEngineInterface cachingEngine)
    {

        _cachingEngine = cachingEngine;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var products = _cachingEngine.GetProducts();
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know it was prob a stupid question, but I honestly am just trying to wrap my head around DI outside of the typical controller\unit test situation and think about how I can apply it in all aspects of my software where it makes sense to do so.

Comment: So, if I wanted to do this outside of a controller, what's the best way?

Comment: That is too vague of a question, it would be the same anywhere, Dependency Injection will inject what you need into the constructor, and you don't use the new keyword, if you are instantiating the class yourself you use the DI service to create it for you

Comment: "if you are instantiating the class yourself you use the DI service to create it for you" Yes, looking to do this.

Comment: @FAtBalloon I would ask another SO question for that